# Manually set values shown in legend for continuous variable of seaborn/matplotlib scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, visualization

Is there a way to manually set the values shown in the legend of a seaborn (or matplotlib) scatterplot when the legend contains a continuous variable (hue)?

For example, in the plot below I might like to show the colors corresponding to values of `[0, 1, 2, 3]` rather than `[1.5, 3, 4.5, 6, 7.5]`

```
np.random.seed(123)
x = np.random.randn(500)
y = np.random.randn(500)
z = np.random.exponential(1, 500)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
hue_norm = (0, 3)
sns.scatterplot(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    hue=z,
    hue_norm=hue_norm,
    palette='coolwarm',
)

ax.grid()
ax.set(xlabel="x", ylabel="y")
ax.legend(title="z")
sns.despine()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seaborn creates its scatterplot a bit different than matplotlib. That way, the scatterplot can be customized in more ways. For the legend, Seaborn 0.13 employs custom `Line2D` elements (older Seaborn versions use `PathCollection`s).

The following approach:

- replaces Seaborn's `hue_norm=(0, 3)` with an equivalent matplotlib norm
- creates dummy `Line2D` elements to serve as legend handles
- copies all properties (size, edgecolor, ...) of the legend handle created by Seaborn
- then changes the marker color depending on the norm and colormap

The approach might need some tweaks if your scatterplot differs. The code has been tested with Matplotlib 3.8.3 and Seaborn 0.13.2 (and 0.12.2).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

np.random.seed(123)
x = np.random.randn(500)
y = np.random.randn(500)
z = np.random.exponential(1, 500)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
hue_norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=3)
sns.scatterplot(x=x, y=y, hue=z, hue_norm=hue_norm, palette='coolwarm', ax=ax)

legend_keys = [0, 1, 2, 3]
handles = [Line2D([], []) for _ in legend_keys]
cmap = plt.get_cmap('coolwarm')
for h, key in zip(handles, legend_keys):
    if type(ax.legend_.legend_handles[0]) == Line2D:
        h.update_from(ax.legend_.legend_handles[0])
    else:
        h.set_linestyle('')
        h.set_marker('o')
        h.set_markeredgecolor(ax.legend_.legend_handles[0].get_edgecolor())
        h.set_markeredgewidth(ax.legend_.legend_handles[0].get_linewidth())
    h.set_markerfacecolor(cmap(hue_norm(key)))
    h.set_label(f'{key}')
ax.legend(handles=handles, title='z')
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn scatterplot with custom legend]

Comment: Hmm might just be a versioning issue but I'm getting `AttributeError: 'Legend' object has no attribute 'legend_handles'`. If I replace that with `ax.legend_.legendHandles[0]` I get `AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute '_linestyle'`

Comment: You are using old seaborn and matplotlib versions. Could you try to upgrade? Anyway, the updated code should now also work with older seaborn versions.

Comment: I'm working with a team so updating is a bit headache. But the new solution worked with this 

```
for h, key in zip(handles, legend_keys):
    h.set_linestyle('')
    h.set_marker('o')
    h.set_markeredgecolor(ax.legend_.legendHandles[0].get_edgecolor())
    h.set_markeredgewidth(ax.legend_.legendHandles[0].get_linewidth())
    h.set_markerfacecolor(cmap(hue_norm(key)))
    h.set_label(f'{key}')
```

Comment: `legendHandles` is deprecated since matplotlib version 3.7

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is

```
plt.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(num=[1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Here is my full code (I used just matplotlib)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(123)
x = np.random.randn(500)
y = np.random.randn(500)
z = np.random.exponential(1, 500)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatter = ax.scatter(x=x, y=y, c=z)

ax.grid()
ax.set(xlabel="x", ylabel="y")
ax.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(num=[1, 2, 3, 4]), title="z")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This doesn't work for Seaborn's scatterplot. The way you called `plt.scatter` doesn't take `hue_norm` into account.  Further, please don't mix matplotlib's [object-oriented](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/) and `pyplot` interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the legend after creating the graphic, you can capture the `Legend` object as a variable and then iterate through the text elements it contains.  The code below replaces the text with the enumerated order.

```
leg = ax.legend(title="z")

...

for i, txt_obj in enumerate(leg.get_texts()):
    txt_obj.set_text(i)
```

Comment: This changes the text, but doesn't adapt the color of the dots.